# SQL Server: Show This month's newly added/removed ID's compared to Last month's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a list of active contracts every month, and curious how I can show the ID's of the contracts that were newly added and removed in this month compared with the month prior to that.

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (     
ContractID  NVARCHAR(255),
Date        DATE    
);      
INSERT INTO Test (ContractID, Date)
VALUES
('C1','12/31/2019'),
('C2','12/31/2019'),
('C3','12/31/2019'),
('C4','12/31/2019'),
('C1','01/31/2020'),
('C2','01/31/2020'),
('C3','01/31/2020'),
('C1','02/28/2020'),
('C2','02/28/2020'),
('C5','02/28/2020')
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

Expected end result:

```
CREATE TABLE Test2 (        
ContractID  NVARCHAR(255),
Date        DATE,
Change      NVARCHAR(255)
);      
INSERT INTO Test2 (ContractID, Date, Change)
VALUES
('C1','12/31/2019','Added'),
('C2','12/31/2019','Added'),
('C3','12/31/2019','Added'),
('C4','12/31/2019','Added'),
('C4','01/31/2020','Removed'),
('C3','02/28/2020','Removed'),
('C5','02/28/2020','Added')
SELECT * FROM Test2
```

Any suggestions / what direction should I be looking for?

Comment: Start by explaining why <null, 12/31/2019, null> appears in your resultset. Because that makes no sense. And what about C3? Was it not removed in Feb?

Comment: Agreed, it should first add all the rows obviously! And C3 is also missing, my bad. I edited the dataset

Comment: This is one of those rare times when, despite how much I despise them, I'd probably go with a trigger... have it write out to an audit/log table values added or deleted (and maybe even edits) to/from the main table.